# Bounds of arc length of a curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, arc-length

The problem I came across asks the following:

> Find the arc length of a curve in its parametric form: $$x=a(2\cos{t}-\cos{2t}),$$ $$y=a(2\sin{t}-\sin{2t})$$

To solve this we can use the formula $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2}dx}$.
We can easily find that $$x'=2a(\sin{2t}-\sin{t}),$$ $$y'=-2a(\cos{2t}-\cos{t})$$

The part where I struggle with is finding $t_1$ and $t_2$. This is a wider problem I have when ever I come across these types of problems. How can I find these bounds if I have no idea how this parametric function looks like? How do I know if we can even calculate arc length just by using the previously written formula? (*e.g. like with circle, where we find it by finding just one quarter of circle and multiplying it with four*) How should I know if  I only got some part of arc length and not the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a circle with the parameterization $x=\cos t$, $y=\sin t$, rather than finding the length of one quarter of the circle and multiplying by $4$, another way to find the length is the recognize that the parameterization is periodic with period $2 \pi$. You can find the arc length by going exactly once around the circle, integrating from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Similarly, with your example, you can recognize from the formulas that the parameterization is also periodic with period $2 \pi$: the $\cos 2t$ and $\sin 2t$ terms have a smaller period of $\pi$, but the $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ have period $2 \pi$, and so the smallest period that all of those terms have in common is $2 \pi$. So for this problem also you can find the arc length by integrating from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Comment: So basically I should try to find the smallest period that all the terms in both $x$ and $y$ have in common?

Comment: For periodic parameterizations, yes. In general not all parameterizations have a period, and for such a problem you would have to do something different.